Why does Helix Nebula look like an eye?
The infrared lights, the material clumps that radiate and the whole view resembling a celestial firework or giant eye

I suggest you take the tour https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tour and did you do any research on your own, trying to find an answer? What makes this particularily surprising and different from why the cloud in my sky here does look like a cute kitty?

I think it is more that people try to make sense of things as if they are human-like: the brain constantly looks for eyes in an image, so something that shows a (small) similarity, will indeed look like an eye. I read somewhere this is also essentially what happens in a psychosis: these "brain circuits" get overactive.

Any on-topic question that produces good answers is a good question. Generally Stack Exchange strongly encourages at least a bit of prior research, but in some cases, it's tough, and I think that this is one of them. One won't find a published paper with the title "Why does Helix Nebula look like an eye?" or "On the eye-shapedness of the Helix Nebula". But in the future, it might be better to include a bit of preliminary research to avoid down votes and sarcastic, gratuitous, and ultimately unhelpful "cute kitty" comments.

The formatting of your question seems to imply it is a quote, but you give no citation or context to the quote or the question. It might improve the question to clarify these matters.

Look at Helix Nebula NGC 7293 (Aquarius) on the left and Ring Nebula M57 (Lyra) on the right. Both are of the planetary nebula type, and very similar.

This NASA video, based on Hubble Space Telescope observations, shows the details of M57's three-dimensional configuration, which is what makes it look like an "eye" from a certain direction.
Probably the three-dimensional configuration of NGC 7293 is very similar and that is why we also see it "like an eye".
Exploring the Structure of the Ring Nebula (NASA)
Best regards.




We can add viewable YouTube videos in posts now Feel free to roll back if you prefer not. Excellent video, thanks!

Thank you very much @uhoh for embedding the video in the post, I didn't know how to do it. Best regards.

Prior to the formation of the Helix Nebula, there was a star similar to our own Sun in its post-main sequence stage.
Eventually, this star consumed its entire fuel supply, which caused fusion to cease and its core to fall into a white dwarf since there was no outward force to resist its own gravity.
With a compressed and hot core, its outside layers expanded and caused its outer material to be released in all directions resulting in a large, elliptical structure. However, due to our orientation in relation to this object, it appears "eye-like", despite having a relatively globular appearance in reality.
You can read more about the Helix Nebula on NASA's page, it offers great insight on it and its formation.

"As the core compressed, it was no longer able to hold its outer layers" That's a bit misleading. A star sheds nearly 50% of its original mass throughout its lifetime, especially during the red giant and AGB phases. Reduction in fusion causes the core to contract, but that increases the core temperature, which causes the outer layers of the star to expand and material to be blown away.

(cont) At the end of this process, the exposed core becomes so hot that its ultraviolet emissions ionize that material, making it into a bright planetary nebula.

@PM2Ring, apologies if that segment was oversimplified, I have expanded on this concept with the additional information.
